# visual studio 2017 large Build error (for hololens build)

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017, hololens, build-error

Sort of fix:
I changed the scripting backend in the player settings from .net to IL2cpp.
Now I can at least build the project.

Software:

Unity 2017.3.1f1
Universal windows platform
Holotoolkit

Visual studio 2017 15.6.1

Problem:

I try to build my solution on the hololens and get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>       Error     The command ""D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Unity\Tools\AssemblyConverter.exe"
>   -platform=uap -lock="D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\project.lock.json"
>   -bits=32 -configuration=Release -removeDebuggableAttribute=False -uwpsdk=10.0.16299.0 -path="." -path="D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Players\UAP\dotnet\x86\Release"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.TextRenderingModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.TerrainPhysicsModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.TerrainModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.TilemapModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.UIElementsModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.SharedInternalsModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.ScreenCaptureModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.SpriteMaskModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.StyleSheetsModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.SpriteShapeModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.VideoModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.VehiclesModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.UnityWebRequestWWWModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.VRModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.WindModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.WebModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.UnityAnalyticsModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.UNETModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.UIModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.UnityConnectModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.UnityWebRequestTextureModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.UnityWebRequestModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.UnityWebRequestAudioModule.dll" "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.AudioModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.AssetBundleModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.ARModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.ClothModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.DirectorModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.CrashReportingModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.CoreModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Assembly-CSharp.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.AccessibilityModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.AnimationModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.AIModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.ParticlesLegacyModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.JSONSerializeModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.ParticleSystemModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.PhysicsModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.Physics2DModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.PerformanceReportingModule.dll" "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.GridModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.GameCenterModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.InputModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.IMGUIModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.ImageConversionModule.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.Timeline.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\nunit.framework.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.UI.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.SpatialTracking.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.Analytics.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.HoloLens.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.StandardEvents.dll"
>   "D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\UnityEngine.Networking.dll""
>   exited with code
>   3.    Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication D:\bewijzenmap\Stage\AR_Productions\Hololens_projects\Heinen-En-Hopman\Heinen&Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Builds\painttest\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication\Heinen_en_Hopman_Hololen_Aplication.csproj 434

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the entire output folder and rebuild the solution. Remember to check the "Unity C# project" check and "Copy reference".

Comment: tried that like 10 times, but thanks for your suggestion. :)